# What is the point in keeping passing unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Let's say I'm developing a method where I can pass in two numbers and get the highest number back.  Since I'm doing this TDD-style, I will have a dozen unit tests and come up with the following implementation:

```
public int GetHighestNumber(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y) return x;
    else return y;
}
```

This works extremely well.

The tests have been used to create the implementation. When the implementation has been finished, what is the point in keeping these unit tests? It's like keeping the scaffolding around the house after the house has already been delivered.

I'm not looking for reasons to have unit tests, or if/when to use TDD. I'm just curious about why unit tests should be kept after the code has been fully implemented, instead of having these tests as a temporary means and removed when it doesn't need to support the developer.

---

**Edit**

After commenting on *CodeGnome* I realized I should emphasize that this is just about the TDD-tests, which are created mainly to point the developer in the right direction. The scaffolding so to speak.

I do appreciate all the comments though.

---

After reading all the messages, I can conclude two things:

1. Nobody on stackoverflow actually reads the original question
2. You should keep those unit tests, not because the tests themselves have any use, but because you're probably working with highly incompetent colleagues and these tests are there to prevent them from doing incredibly stupid things

Comment: Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 9):

Real life code is almost never "finished".

Requirements change and expand. Features are added. Despite TDD, there are bugs to be fixed.

Unit tests also work as regression tests, to prove that the code still works after these changes. This is in fact the most valuable aspect of unit tests (any TDD proponent who claims that it's less important that the design benefits is deluding themselves).

Comment: +1 for mentioning mentioning regression testing. Having good regression set you sleep so well at nights!

Comment: It is true that real life code is never finished. But the example will never change. Most code is either this simple or it should be this simple. You already have tests that will test the bigger picture. Any bugs appearing in that process will be picked up there.

Comment: But what's the point to rewrite test every single time the code is change ? O_o

Comment: @Jeroen: I would say that almost NO code is this simple, nor can it be made this simple. If it were, you wouldn't need tests at all.

Comment: @Rangi Lin: If you have to *rewrite* the tests, there's something catastrophically wrong with your design. Normally you only have to adjust tests on a similar scale to the code to be tested, and the point is the same as why you write the tests in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Actually I am just wondering why Jeroen would want to remove the test and write it again when code need to be change.

Comment: @RangiLin: I'm saying not every code in your system needs to change. If it is likely that it could change, have as many tests as you want. But that is not always the case.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Actually, my experience is that it IS that simple or can be rewritten to be that simple (I am talking about the individual units). Most developers actually like creating code that is too complicated.

Comment: @Jeroen: if you simplify individual units excessively, all you achieve is that unit tests become almost meaningless make-work while all their importance passes to the integration tests, because integrations is where the complexity of the code hase moved to, making it overall harder to understand.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - You could say that the complexity is supposed to be on that level

Comment: @Jeroen: the problem with complexity at the integration level is that it's harder to understand since the elements that cause it (individual methods/functions) can often not be easily viewed together, and that each of them has syntactic overhead that contributes to overall code bloat.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - True, integration level is harder to understand , and it should be (but it can't be _that_ much harder). Having unit tests doesn't solve this problem and it will never be a replacement for good logging and good coding practice. Of course in real life, not many projects do either of those things, but that's a different problem. I'm just wondering why anyone would like to keep the unit tests that are created only for helping the developer create a unit effectively (again, not talking about the other tests).

Answer (score 5):

A few reasons (at least) come to mind:

- they help document what your code is supposed / not supposed to do
- corollary: they provide future developers with sample uses of your method
- they act as regression tests if you want to change your method at a later stage: you can check that the original tests still pass after your changes and that you have not broken anything

**EDIT**

*"no changes will ever be made to that method and regression tests on that level are unnecessary"*

Until some smart guy arrives and changes the code to

```
if (x - y > 0) return x;
else return y;
```

(yes it can and will happen, if not in that method, somewhere else).

Hopefully, one of your test will be:

```
assertEquals(Integer.MAX_VALUE, GetHighestNumber(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

And that test will fail.

Comment: Aren't those reasons already covered by calling the method 'GetHighestNumber'? Once that method works as expected, no changes will ever be made to that method and regression tests on that level are unnecessary. I'm specifically talking about tests on that level, not the bigger picture. Those will be handled by different tests.

Comment: No test will ever be able to prevent developers from doing stupid things (like reimplementing a method that already works perfectly). I assume some competence level of the other developers.

Comment: @Jeroen on this contrived example it might seem obvious, but not all methods are 2 lines of code (and if they are, they most likely only require one or 2 tests if any). Ps: this was a real life example (almost - it was in a comparison method).

Comment: I think that we have a difference of opinion here. Granted, most applications have a lot of methods that are more that a few lines of code, but I think it doesn't have to be. The ["Object Calisthenics" chapter](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/uploads/2012/ObjectCalisthenics.pdf) of The ThoughtWorks Anthology gives several simple rules to follow in implementing good OO design.

Answer (score 3):

#### Tests Prevent Regressions

A properly implemented unit test validates program behavior. The "legacy" tests ensure that as you expand or modify your program, you don't accidentally introduce new bugs or create regressions in your code.

Tests can certainly be refactored along with your code if they no longer serve a clear purpose as your code evolves. However, if a feature was worth testing in the first place, it remains useful to continue testing that behavior throughout the life-cycle of your code.

If you find your unit tests contain a lot of "useless" tests, you may be testing the wrong things (e.g. composition rather than behavior), or may simply need to refactor your tests to prevent the tests from growing stale over time. I would certainly never recommend removing them altogether, as they are *sanity checks* and not just legacy scaffolding.

Comment: I absolutely agree that if there was a reason worth testing, you should keep it. I think that the tests in TDD aren't those kind of tests. They are just there to point the developer in the right direction to implement a feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Regression, regression, for million times regression.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression)

Imagine hypothetical situation where you have no tests after feature is implemented:

1. You implement montly-report feature for your application. For the sake of example, let's say it pulls entities from database, scans their definition and creates appropriate tables.
2. You release the reports feature, your client is happy that it all works and creates nice shiny tables just like he wanted.
3. Some time later, your friend does some internal work on data access layer. He changes few entities definition to optimize database things.
4. You release this as *impotant patch*. Client is again happy, your application seems to work much faster now.
5. Few days later, you receive a phone call from irritated client claiming that reports generate some garbage.

Who's to blame? You, of course. What happened? Your code stopped working. Maybe it never worked at all? Maybe it worked in one special case? Leaving this silly questions aside, everybody knows what really happened; changes made in entities code *broke* report generation feature. Your friend caused the problem, you take the blame.

This is why you have automated tests (not only *unit* naturally). To **prevent regression**. It's very hard to spot bugs caused by regression manually. They might appear immediately after change, some time later, some other change later. You never know. And that's where unit tests (along other methods of testing) help. From the hypothetical situation above, your friend would have known he broke your report generator code if he had run tests. Simple as that.

Few to-the-point comments from [this programmers.SE question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/are-unit-tests-really-that-useful):

> Colleges expose unit tests as something you must do out of sheer faith, without explaining in detail **there is a disease to prevent and control and that that disease is called *regression***.
>
> Unit tests don't prove your code is free from defects, but they do raise your confidence (or should...) that the code does what you designed it to do, and continues to do tomorrow what it does today.

Something to have in mind whenever you start wondering whether you really need all those tests.

Comment: Preventing regression should be done with bigger tests. In the hypothetical situation you describe there is clearly a reasonable chance it will change, and therefore tests are needed. I'm just talking about unit tests where those tests will never fail again (like in the GetHighestNumber above).

Comment: @Jeroen: claiming some code will never change is quite bold statement, can you really be sure of that? My experience shows that this is rarely true, your experience might support your claims. It's hard to argue on those grounds. Overall I noticed you make quite dangerous assumptions - never changing code, developers competence. They say it's better to be safe then sorry and I hope you won't get bitten by those :-)

Comment: Bad developers also write bad unit tests and change or even remove unit tests that interfere with their changes. You don't want to know much time I spend in fixing their unit tests because I fixed a bug. I'm not saying that no code will ever change, but most people (especially the ones that posted an answer to this question, which I appreciate btw) seem to think that every possible line of code have a realistic chance of changing. I don't agree with that statement.

Answer (score 0):

TDD rocks. Your right TDD facilitates design. So tests that do not fail have little, or no value after the code is written. Their existence however does provide a feeling of a safety belt to encourage refactoring. But if your code followed open/closed principles then the tests may be considered of no further use once the code is written.

The rule I follow is if the original design holds and I'm implementing minor changes in requirements (e.g. builds string with a lower case prefix) the the tests do help, they avoid regression. However, if I realize that the design or intend to the class was just plain wrong then unit tests can be an inhibitor to change (change does not equal refactor).

The hard part is recognizing change of intent from change in requirements.

As usual there is not black and white answer.

Answer (score 0):

TDD is the more relevant, the bigger a project must scale.

When working on big complex projects, there are many dependencies between code parts at all levels. A bug fix on one point can lead to the discovery of new bugs in other parts immediately with automated tests.

As soon as you gain experience in one such big project, you will see how valuable that is.

Comment: Those dependencies shouldn't make a difference if you test at unit-level. There are always good reasons to have tests that test the bigger picture. I'm talking about the very small units, like the GetHighestNumber example above. Those tests will never fail, so what is the point in keeping them?

Answer (score 0):

With the code above you have the following tests:

- X greater than Y, X returned.
- Y greater than X, Y returned.
- X equal to Y, Y returned.

So three short, quick-running tests that document the expected behavour of that method and enforce it. (Both very good reason for keeping them).

Now if you have significantly more than the three tests above then you can start trimming down the number of tests. Like all code, it should be refactored and deleted when not required, but make sure you are deleting just what is not required.

Comment: I don't think any programmer will have the wrong expectation about a method named 'GetHighestNumber'.

Comment: I've come across methods that don't do what you think they do (they did once but were slowly changed).
To put a different way, what is the harm in keeping the three tests? We have benefits (even if you feel them small).

Comment: Now if I'm honest, I would never have written the method above, instead I would have used an existing API (I'm sure if the platform did not support it, a common util library would. Any tests would be from the layer above.

Comment: That's sounds more of a problem of the competence level of the developers (to put it delicately). There is no real harm in keeping them, but YAGNI comes to mind. That example is of course not a serious example, but just to show a method that is so simple that everybody understands

Comment: A better example might be on I encountered recently. A test made sure an association was mapped as a many-to-one in NHibernate, instead of a property. It has been mapped as a many-to-one for the last 2 years and that test passed for the last 2 years.

Comment: Hibernate tests I'd not keep. / Yes it is a problem with the developers. Alas not everyone who will work on the code base will be competent.

Comment: Neither do I. I removed that test for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 0):

The tests should be serving your team as documentation for the modules. They show the reader examples of entrance values and expected exit values. They should give a clear instruction to the next guy how to call the routine.

I've noticed in a lot of your comments above that you assume a lot about the next programmer to come along, that he will be smart and competent, that he will read your code carefully, that he will trust your method names.  Making those assumptions is dangerous. Maybe not under your boss today, but it's likely that at some point your code is going to be maintained by someone less capable than your current assumptions indicate.

Think of it this way: if your code goes open source, and suddenly hundreds of people of varying levels of competence are looking at it, will all of them understand it? Probably not.

What is obvious to the author of a module is often not so obvious to others.

Comment: Like I said in the post, I'm not really interested in reasons to have unit tests. Just the scaffolding you create when doing TDD and why you should keep tests that will never fail (like the example above).

Comment: Here's an example: imagine you have an int Add(T x, T y) method on a template that ends with "return x+y;".  And someone comes along and puts an operator overload redefining "plus" to be "concatenate".  Your always passing test of ensuring Add("2", "2") returns 4 now breaks because it returns 22.  Contrived, but I've seen worse.